# Суммирование столбцов по условию

Tags: sql, select, vba

В макросе написан следующий запрос:

```
"select sku.id,sku.skucode,sku.name,sum(nvl(v_rs2_current_stock13d.qty,0)) qty,sku.uom,sku.weight_netto " & _
   "from sku left join v_rs2_current_stock13d on v_rs2_current_stock13d.sku_id=sku.id and nvl(v_rs2_current_stock13d.warehouse_id, 100) not in (1, 2) " & _
   "where nvl(v_rs2_current_stock13d.warehouse_id, 100) not in (1, 2) and sku.id>0 and ((upper(SUBSTR(trim(sku.skucode),4,1)) like '%W%' " & _
   "or upper(SUBSTR(trim(sku.skucode),4,1)) like '%V%' " & _
   "or upper(SUBSTR(trim(sku.skucode),4,1)) like '%R%' " & _
   "and SUBSTR(sku.skucode,8,1) is null) or v_rs2_current_stock13d.qty>0) " & _
   "group by sku.id,sku.skucode,sku.name,sku.uom,sku.weight_netto order by skucode;"
```

Нужно чтобы в столбце qty было суммировано кол-во по следующим условиям:

1. Если в столбце sku.uom единица измерения равна unit и kg, то просто суммируется общее кол-во в столбце qty. как и есть на данный момент
2. Если в столбце sku.uom единица измерения равна upak то суммируется общее кол-во в столбце qty и перемножается на данный в столбце sku.weight_netto.

Answer (score 0):

```
SUM( CASE WHEN sku.uom IN ('unit', 'kg') THEN v_rs2_current_stock13d.qty
          WHEN sku.uom IN ('upak')       THEN v_rs2_current_stock13d.qty * sku.weight_netto
          ELSE                                0
     END ) qty
```

Comment: Спасибо большое пол дня пытался прописать правильно все эти case и when, не получалось. Теперь все работает